# Storing a java object as a field in Solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj

While indexing document on solr , i want to perform some preprocessing and store the synonyms of the words in the document . I want it to be associated with the file and hence i am planning to store this java 2d array as a field in solr .

```
 How can i add a java object as a field while indexing files in solr ?
```

In lucene i have seen that the field can be a byte array and hence i serialize my object and store it as a byte array and later retrieve it !

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Solr+Field+Types#SolrFieldTypes-WorkingwithExternalFiles).
Also, you can try to save it as a multivalued field with a JAXB/JSON serializer or similar.

Comment: +1 for JSON serialization - also handy it as can be used in browser with JS or other client apps.